# UIActivityViewController show showing ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to present an activity view controller. but I don't know why is this error occurs again and again. Same code I have used for my other app and its working fine over there. However, in my current app its starts crashing.

```
NSString *url=@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APPNAME/idXXXXXXXXX";
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download App %@ and get free reward points!",url];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[title];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
if (activityViewController == nil){
   return;
}
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

[image]

Comment: This code looks fine ... you have to debug and find out where exactly its crashing.

Comment: Could you try adding an exception break point to see if u get more information about what is causing the crash ?

Comment: I just tried out your code and it runs fine. I did get exceptions related to popoverpresentationController and fixed it. But I dont think that is the case here.

Comment: Is that iPad or iPhone?

Comment: i found issue that there is some issue with my navigation controller. Its allow me to pushtoviewController but when i use PresentViewController it will crash with the above error...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with main thread mention in below.

```
NSString *url=@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APPNAME/idXXXXXXXXX";
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download App %@ and get free reward points!",url];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[title];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
if (activityViewController == nil){
    return;
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
});
```

Comment: i found that my navigation is able to perform push action but not able to perform present action... i dont know why its behaving like that....